# VirtualBox: Unable to ping host from guest using HOST-ONLY Network Configuration

Tags: virtualbox

I installed two  windows servers (VM1 and VM2) on a Virtual box running on Windows 10 using HOST-ONLY Network configuration, with the following IP specification.

HOST IP:  10.x.x.x

VM1 IP:   192.x.x.x

VM2 IP:   192.x.x.x

VM1 and VM2 have the same subnets.

Here is the PROBLEM: I can ping from VM1 and VM2 and vise versa. I can ping from HOST to both VM1 and VM2. However, I can NOT ping from VM1 to HOST and also I can NOT ping from VM2 to host. I have been struggling with these issues for days. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: In *Virtualbox manager > File > Preferences > Network > Host Only Adapters > Edit*, ensure that its IP is inside the `192.x.x.x` range and ends with `1`.

Comment: Please avoid redacting [Private IPs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses) as there's no reason to but only make troubleshooting harder. I assume by `HOST IP: 10.x.x.x` you are referring to some physical LAN IP on the host which is irrelevant. You should check the IP that's relevant with `ipconfig /all` or so (e.g. the config page in VB harry mentioned above). Most likely it's a firewall problem btw (Windows Firewall does NOT by default allow inbound ping AFAIK).

Comment: Your goal is an insecure machine. No other way to look at it.